# How to store fields in a text file into a list or map and then compare with fields in other text file in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, file-io, bufferedreader

```
Text file1
2348384#Test 123####3983#Data 22 ....
```

etc this file1 has many fields that are separted by "#" character and there are many rows in the file.

```
Text file  2
23,809,Test 88, Dat 33
```

File 2 has fields separated by comma and its has many rows.

I need to compare if fields from file match in file2. Many fields are same in the 2 files, so i need to write code to match if both are same?

Should i store all fields in file 1 into a String[]

Say i want to compare Row 4 ,field 9 , String[3]

or should i store individuals fields in a String variable..

How can i compare fields in 2 text files in java? SHould i store all lines in a file in a List or HashMap?

thanks.

Comment: Pick an approach and try it.

Comment: Yes store it in String[]  and use the split function wisely. You are good to go!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this? Sorry if this is messy code

```
public final static void main(final String[] args) {
    // file1 content:
    // a###b###c#d
    // e###f###g#h
    List<String> list1 = getListFromFile(new File("\\file1.txt"));

    // file2 content:
    // a,b,c,d
    // e,f,g,h
    final List<String> list2 = getListFromFile(new File("\\file2.txt"));

    list1 = format(list1);

    if (get(list1, 2, 3).equals(get(list2, 2, 4))) {
        System.out.println("Equal!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not Equal!");
    }

}


final static String get(final List<String> list, final int row, final int field) {

    final String[] strs = list.get(row - 1).split(",");

    /*
     * Handle IndexOutOfBoundsException
     */

    return strs[field - 1].trim();
}

final static List<String> format(final List<String> list1) {
    final List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
        newList.add(list1.get(i).replaceAll("[#]+", ","));
    }

    return newList;
}

final static List<String> getListFromFile(final File file) {
    List<String> listOfFile = new ArrayList<>();
    try (final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            listOfFile.add(line);
        }

        return listOfFile;
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        /*
         * Catch it
         */
    }
    return null;
}
```